# Request a GET failed in Node

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I am requesting a `GET` to a 3rd party api service from my `node` back-end.
I am getting a response of `403 forbidden`:

```
request("http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=my_api_key&field_list=name,image,id&format=json&limit=1&query=street%20fighter%203&resources=game",(err,res,body) => {
    console.log(body);
})
```

Querying the same request in my browser return the expected results.
Any idea why this can happen?

EDIT:

Logging the response body, I receive the following page (without the JS):

```
<h1>Wordpress RSS Reader, Anonymous Bot or Scraper Blocked</h1>
<p>
    Sorry we do not allow WordPress plugins to scrape our site. They tend to be used maliciously to steal our content. We do not allow scraping of any kind.
    You can load our RSS feeds using any other reader but you may not download our content.
    <a href='/feeds'>Click here more information on our feeds</a>
</p>
<p>
    Or you're running a bot that does not provide a unique user agent.
    Please provide a UNIQUE user agent that describes you. Do not use a default user agent like "PHP", "Java", "Ruby", "wget", "curl" etc.
    You MUST provide a UNIQUE user agent. ...and for God's sake don't impersonate another bot like Google Bot that will for sure
    get you permanently banned.
</p>
<p>
    Or.... maybe you're running an LG Podcast player written by a 10 year old. Either way, Please stop doing that.
</p>
```

Comment: That URL appears malformed, why is there a slash prior to the query parameters? Have you considered logging, copying and pasting *precisely* the URL your software is using into your browser, or did you retype it?

Comment: I have copy and paste it exactly as it is in my code to my browser. I tried removing that slash in the browser, but when sending the request it was added again.

Comment: Do you have any state in the browser (cookies, etc.)? Does it still work from an anonymous browser window?

Comment: The first request is clear from any cookies and state, every following request contains a cookie. I opened a new window in incognito mode, sent the request and received the expected response. No state is shown in the request headers. The response header contains `set-cookie` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this service requires User-Agent in headers, see this example

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=my_api_key&field_list=name,image,id&format=json&limit=1&query=street%20fighter%203&resources=game',
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'test' },
  json: true
}

rp(options)
  .then(result => {
    // process result
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // handle error
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Include User-Agent header in request like this

```
var options = {
  url: 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?  api_key=my_api_key&field_list=name,image,id&format=json&limit=1&query=street%20fighter%203&resources=game',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

request(options, (err,res,body) => {
    console.log(body);
})
```

Comment: Should I set the `User-Agent` as 'request'? Because I'm still getting the same `403`.

Comment: just checked http://www.giantbomb.com/api/documentation documentation and there is no custom requirement for User-Agent header text, so you can set any non empty string. 
After seting header I receive this response on backend:  `{"error":"Invalid API Key","limit":0,"offset":0,"number_of_page_results":0,"number_of_total_results":0,"status_code":100,"results":[]}`

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your time. Sending a fake api key in the browser I receive the same result you posted. Sending the same fake api key from my node app, I receive 403 forbidden, while in the browser it's 200 OK. I really don't get it...

Comment: Hey man, It gives you 3 reason why it may fail:
1) it doesn't allow wordpress plugins to access there content.
2) user-agent should be unique try `CandroidBot` or think up something unique 
3) Maybe your IP address is in a blocked, send message to support